How to get history message from pubsub with js-libp2p?
I have a pubsub connection between two nodes with js-libp2p
const libp2p = await createLibp2p({
  addresses: {
    listen: [
      '/webrtc'
    ]
  },
  transports: [
    webSockets({
      filter: filters.all
    }),
    webRTC(),
    circuitRelayTransport({
      discoverRelays: 1
    })
  ],
  connectionEncryption: [noise()],
  streamMuxers: [yamux()],
  connectionGater: {
    denyDialMultiaddr: () => {
      return false
    }
  },
  services: {
    identify: identify(),
    pubsub: gossipsub(),
    dcutr: dcutr()
  },
  connectionManager: {
    minConnections: 0
  }
})

I see this methods.
  libp2p.services.pubsub.getSubscribers()
  libp2p.services.pubsub.subscribe(topic)
  libp2p.services.pubsub.publish


Is it possible to get the history of written messages when connecting the second node?
Or where can i see interface where i will see of help about history message ?

No one keeps a history.  If there's stuff that every new subscriber needs to see, then the publisher needs to send that.
